# Nondegenerate bilinear map

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

Let $V$ be the vector space consists of all $n\times n$ real matrices, and $f$ is a nonvanishing linear function on $V$ such that
$$f(AB)=f(BA),\ \forall\ A,B\in V.$$
Show that $g(A,B)=f(AB)$ is a non-degenerate bilinear function on $V$.

What I could show is only "g" is bilinear.

Comment: What remains to show? Which properties of $f$ didn't you use yet?

Comment: I could not argue anymore.